# Collapse sub-trees in a tree with average distance to tips < x

Tags: python, tree, formatting, hierarchy, transformation

I have a hierarchical tree in Newick format, such as:

```
(A:0.556705,(B:0.251059,C:0.251059):0.305646):0.556705;
```

Parentheses represent tree topology (clade structure/groupings) and numbers represent branch lengths (distances), such that:

[image]

I need to collapse clades (sub-trees) whose average distances to the tips (terminal nodes/tips/leaves) are less than a given value, x. Such that input and collapsed output are in Newick format. For example, if x was 0.29, then B and C in the above collapsed into BC, we get something like:

```
(A:0.556705,BC:0.556705):0.556705;
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to programmatically achieve this collapsing given any Newick tree (e.g. in Python)?

Comment: Are `0.251059` the distances (relevant for collapsing) of `B` and `C` or is it `0.305646`? (Never worked with clades.)

Comment: oops! cheers you actually made me realise a typo in the post, the 0.251059 is the branch length of B and C to their common parental node (where they split) and the 0.305646 is the distance from their parental node to the root of the tree. Does that make sense? (looking at the diagram helps)

Comment: Now which one must be less than the limit in order to collapse? The distance from the direct ancestor to a terminal or the distance from the root to the terminal?

Comment: it depends, for instance, if x was 0.29 then B and C would collapse into BC and no other clades will collapse (the whole tree counts as a clade itself) if x was 0.6 then the whole tree will collapse into ABC

Comment: OK, then take a look at my answer and check to see if this is what you need.

Comment: Sorry for being so naive, but I am not sure what to provide in the argument for Tree.collapse(self,limit)

Comment: See the last few lines of my code. `collapse` takes one argument which is the limit for collapsing (i.e. the value below which the average must be in order to collapse).

Comment: I have added a second, clearer code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick and **dirty** code snippet seems to work on your minimal tree, but I would need more sample data to check it with more complex trees:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, tokens):
        self.children = []
        while tokens:
            self.children.append ( (tokens [1], float (tokens [0] ) ) )
            tokens = tokens [2:]

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '<{}>'.format (self.children)

    def pprint (self, indent = 0):
        prefix = '  ' * indent
        for child, dist in self.children:
            if isinstance (child, Tree):
                print (prefix, dist)
                child.pprint (indent + 1)
            else:
                print (prefix, child, dist)

    def collapse (self, limit):
        self.children = [ (child.collapse (limit) [0], dist)
            if isinstance (child, Tree)
            else (child, dist) for child, dist in self.children]
        avg = sum (dist for _, dist in self.children) / len (self.children)
        if avg > limit:
            return (self, 0)
        else:
            if any (isinstance (child, Tree) for child in self.children):
                print ('Would like to collapse, but cannot, as at least one child is a tree.')
                return (self, 0)
            return (''.join (child for child, _ in self.children), 0)


def parse (tree):
    stack = []
    buff = ''
    while True:
        c = tree [0]
        if c == ';': break
        tree = tree [1:]
        if c == '(':
            stack.insert (0, '(')
            continue
        if c == ')':
            if buff: stack.insert (0, buff)
            buff = ''
            popped = ''
            tokens = []
            while True:
                token = stack [0]
                stack = stack [1:]
                if token == '(': break
                tokens.append (token)
            stack.insert (0, Tree (tokens) )
            continue
        if c in ':,':
            if buff: stack.insert (0, buff)
            buff = ''
            continue
        buff += c
    if buff: stack.insert (0, buff)
    return Tree (stack)

t = parse ('(A:0.556705,(B:0.251059,C:0.251059):0.305646):0.556705;')
t.pprint ()
t.collapse (.3)
print ()
t.pprint ()
```

The uncollapsed tree is:

```
 0.556705
   0.305646
     C 0.251059
     B 0.251059
   A 0.556705
```

The collapsed tree by .3 is:

```
 0.556705
   CB 0.305646
   A 0.556705
```

The collapsed tree by 1.0 is:

```
CBA 0.556705
```

The collapsed tree by 0.1 is:

```
 0.556705
   0.305646
     C 0.251059
     B 0.251059
   A 0.556705
```

---

Here another cleaner version of the code (which produces nerwick notation output):

**NOTA BENE**: The input tree must be parenthesized.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, weight, children):
        self.weight = weight
        self.children = children [:]

    def distances (self, curDistance = .0, acc = None):
        if acc is None: acc = []
        for child in self.children:
            child.distances (self.weight + curDistance, acc)
        return acc

    def collapse (self, limit):
        self.children = [child.collapse (limit) for child in self.children]
        distances = self.distances (-self.weight)
        avg = sum (distances) / len (distances)
        if avg > limit: return self
        return Node (self.weight, ''.join (self.descendants () ) )

    def descendants (self):
        descendants = []
        for child in self.children:
            descendants.extend (child.descendants () )
        return descendants

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '({}):{}'.format (','.join (str (child) for child in self.children), self.weight)

class Node:
    def __init__ (self, weight, name):
        self.weight = weight
        self.name = name

    def distances (self, curDistance, acc):
        acc.append (curDistance + self.weight)

    def collapse (self, limit):
        return self

    def descendants (self):
        return [self.name]

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '{}:{}'.format (self.name, self.weight)

class Stack (list):
    def pop (self):
        e = self [0]
        del self [0]
        return e

    def push (self, e):
        self.insert (0, e)

def parse (tree):
    buff = ''
    stack = Stack ()
    while True:
        c = tree [0]
        if c == ';': break
        tree = tree [1:]

        if c == '(':
            stack.push (c)
            continue

        if c in ':,':
            if buff: stack.push (buff)
            buff = ''
            continue

        if c == ')':
            if buff: stack.push (buff)
            buff = ''
            popped = ''
            children = []
            while True:
                weight = stack.pop ()
                if weight == '(': break
                weight = float (weight)
                child = stack.pop ()
                if isinstance (child, Tree):
                    child.weight = weight
                else:
                    child = Node (weight, child)
                children.append (child)
            stack.push (Tree (0, children) )
            continue

        buff += c

    return stack.pop ()

t = parse ('((A:0.9,(B:0.2,C:0.3):0.3,(E:0.05,F:0.08):0.1):0.6);')
print ('Input tree is {}'.format (t) )
for limit in range (1, 6):
    limit = limit / 10
    print ('Collapsed by {} is {}'.format (limit, t.collapse (limit) ) )
```

Output is (with modified input):

```
Input tree is (((F:0.08,E:0.05):0.1,(C:0.3,B:0.2):0.3,A:0.9):0.6):0
Collapsed by 0.1 is ((FE:0.1,(C:0.3,B:0.2):0.3,A:0.9):0.6):0
Collapsed by 0.2 is ((FE:0.1,(C:0.3,B:0.2):0.3,A:0.9):0.6):0
Collapsed by 0.3 is ((FE:0.1,CB:0.3,A:0.9):0.6):0
Collapsed by 0.4 is ((FE:0.1,CB:0.3,A:0.9):0.6):0
Collapsed by 0.5 is (FECBA:0.6):0
```

Comment: not sure the second version works properly or if I am being silly.. I am getting: "ValueError: zero length field name in format"

Comment: @hello_there_andy Make sure your tree is parenthesised. Also, I only parse trees in the format marked as "popular" on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format. So if you use another one of the remaining 7 formats, feel free to patch the parser or to convert the input.

Comment: Actually I just copy-pasted your code as it was, hmm

Answer (score 1):

Here maybe a more robust parser which eats all examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format).

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.name = ''
        self.length = None
        self.children = []

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '({}){}{}'.format (
                ','.join (str (child) for child in self.children),
                self.name,
                ':{}'.format (self.length) if self.length is not None else '')

class Node:
    def __init__ (self, name = ''):
        self.name = name
        self.length = None

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '{}{}'.format (self.name, ':{}'.format (self.length) if self.length is not None else '')

class Stack (list):
    def push (self, e):
        self.append (e)

    def pop (self):
        e = self [-1]
        del self [-1]
        return e

    def peek (self):
        return self [-1]

class UnexpectedSymbolException (Exception): pass

def parseNameOrLength (stack, buff):
        if stack.peek () == ':':
            try: length = float (buff)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError ('Non-numeric length "{}" at position {}.'.format (buff, pos) )
            stack.pop ()
            stack.peek ().length = length
        elif buff:
            stack.peek ().name = buff

def parse (tree):
    stack = Stack ()
    stack.push (Tree () )
    buff = ''
    pos = -1
    tree = tree.strip ()
    while True:
        pos += 1
        c = tree [0]
        tree = tree [1:].strip ()
        if tree: la = tree [0]

        if c == '(':
            if buff:
                raise UnexpectedSymbolException (
                        'Unexpected symbol {} at position {}.'.format (c, pos) )
            if la == '(': stack.push (Tree () )
            else: stack.push (Node () )
            continue

        if c == ')':
            parseNameOrLength (stack, buff)
            buff = ''

            child = stack.pop ()
            stack.peek ().children.append (child)
            continue

        if c in ',;':
            parseNameOrLength (stack, buff)
            buff = ''

            if c == ';': return stack.pop ()

            child = stack.pop ()
            stack.peek ().children.append (child)
            if la == '(': stack.push (Tree () )
            else: stack.push (Node () )
            continue

        if c == ':':
            if stack.peek () == ':':
                raise UnexpectedSymbolException (
                        'Unexpected symbol {} at position {}.'.format (c, pos) )
            stack.peek ().name = buff
            stack.push (':')
            buff = ''
            continue

        buff += c

tests = '''(,,(,));
        (A,B,(C,D));
        (A,B,(C,D)E)F;
        (:0.1,:0.2,(:0.3,:0.4):0.5);
        (:0.1,:0.2,(:0.3,:0.4):0.5):0.0;
        (A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5);
        (A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;
        ((B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.1)A;'''.split ('\n')

for test in tests: print (parse (test) )
```